# How to open files from a remote server using HTML

Tags: html, file, remote-server

Is there any option to open files from a remote server using HTML?

I am currently using "file" protocol and it is not suported anymore and I am stuck because I can't find a solution to open it using HTML.

This is my current code

```
<a href="file://\\SERVER\files\file.pdf" target="_blank">Open File</a>
```

Comment: When you say 'open', what exactly do you mean? Would you like the file to open in the browser?

Comment: You can't use `file:///` remotely, you need a standard `http://` and then that server needs to find it for you, and pass it back, all that done using server side code.

Comment: Yes i wanted it to open in the browser.

Comment: So there's no way to open it through HTML now? Only setting up a webserver on my remote server to access it

Answer (score -1):

If you don't define an absolute address, html will search the file in the server where your page is hosted.

```
 //It means that there is a folder named images on the same location of your html page.
 <a href="/images/myFile.jpg">

 //It means that there is a folder in the parent folder of your html page named images on the same location of your html page.
 <a href="../images/myFile.jpg">
```

Or you can define an absolute address to download or open your file :

```
  <a href="http://yourdomain.com/images/myFile.jpg">
```

Comment: Please say why downvote if not, downvoting doesn't have any meaning. I believe that there are some people who downvote for downvoting only.